# Adicionar pasta com imagens no servidor web glassfish

Tags: java-ee, glassfish

Boa tarde, pessoal como faço para deixar uma pasta no meu servidor glassfish com algumas imagens? Ai quando eu precisar eu acesso direto essa url..

Alguém já fez isso?

Answer (score 2):

caso você queira acessar uma pasta fora do escopo resources, uma prática interessante seria o uso de Servlets, esse possibilitará você resgatar uma imagem, ou arquivo, fora até da pasta do Glassfish, você ainda pode colocar alguma segurança nesse acesso, criando restrições de acesso, segue o exemplo abaixo:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/sistema/img-pessoa", "/sistema/cand/img-pessoa"}) //URI's onde seu Servlet vai atender as requests
public class ImgPessoaServlet extends HttpServlet
{
private String imagePath;

public void init() throws ServletException
{}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    File image = new File("");
    String contentType = null;

    String cam = request.getParameter("cam");        

    if(cam != null)
    {
        cam = cam.replace("\\", File.separator);
        cam = cam.replace("/", File.separator);

        if (!cam.contains("pessoaf") && !cam.contains("pessoaj"))
        {
            File img = new File(File.separator + "opt" + File.separator + "arquivos" + File.separator + "fotos" + File.separator + "sem-foto.jpg");

            response.reset();
            response.setContentType("image");
            response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(img.length()));

            Files.copy(img.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
            return;
        }

        image = new File(Util.IMAGEM_PESSOA_PATH + cam);            
    }           

    //System.out.println(image.getAbsolutePath());

    if (!image.exists())
    {
        File img = new File(File.separator + "opt" + File.separator + "arquivos" + File.separator + "fotos" + File.separator + "sem-foto.jpg");
        response.reset();
        response.setContentType("image");
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(img.length()));

        Files.copy(img.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
        return;
    }

    contentType = getServletContext().getMimeType(image.getName());

    if ((contentType == null) || (!contentType.startsWith("image")))
    {
        response.sendError(404);
        return;
    }

    response.reset();
    response.setContentType(contentType);
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(image.length()));

    Files.copy(image.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
}
```

A chamada no seu formulario.xhtml ficaria algo como, supondo que você estivesse utilizando a framework do primefaces:

```
<p:graphicImage id="fotoAmpliada" url="img-pessoa?cam=#{pessoaFBean.fotoPessoa.caminho}"/>
```

Essa é uma implementação resumida que encontrei nesse site:
[exemplo de servlet](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2007/04/imageservlet.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ivan, teoricamente tudo que estiver dentro de WebContent estará disponível para acessar via URL, faço isso com algumas imagens simples em meus sistemas, dessa forma:

```
/home/<Aplicação>/WebContent/resources
```

Crio sempre uma pasta resources e coloco dividido em subpastas de acordo com o objetivo das imagens ou outros arquivos (psf, xls etc..)

Comment: Entendi, legal.. mais no glassish por exemplo o servidor que estou utlizando, eu tenho que apontar para esse caminho né? como faço isso?

Comment: No meu caso, tenho uma aplicação rodando, que monta a pasta quando está ativa (isso é automático no glassfish), ai a URL fica `http://server:8080/aplicacao/nome-da-pasta`. Pode ser uma aplicação JSF simples sem nada só com as pastas que você quer lá. (essa é a forma mais fácil). Dá também pra você tentar configurar alguma coisa diretamente no glasssfish (config), assim como fazemos virtualHosts no apache, mas não saberia como te dar detalhes.